# Problem with citation

Tags: bibtex

I have a very particular problem that a minus of a bibtex entry is not printed in the final bibliography. The entry is the following

```
@article{OBrien1970,
  author = {D. E. O'Brien and L. T. Weinstock and C. C. Cheng},
  title = {{Synthesis of 10-deazariboflavin and related 2,4‐dioxopyrimido[4,5-b]quinolines}},
  journal = {J. Heterocycl. Chem.},
  volume = {7},
  year = {1970},
  pages = {99--105}
}
```

and I'm using BibTeX, Version 0.99d with a the `achemso.bst` style file. The final entry
[image]
is however lacking the minux in front of "dioxopyrimidio". How do I print it?

Comment: Can you try to remove that hyphen and type it again using the hyphen (minus sign) in the keyboard. It sometimes happens if we copy from another document and paste into tex editor.

Comment: I can confirm @TrungDung's suspicion: The vanishing hyphen is the unicode character 'HYPHEN' (0xe28090 in UTF8), whereas all the other hyphens are plain one-byte hyphens (0x2d), check e.g. with any online text-to-hex converter

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Sometimes the solution is so simple.